# Get ID through code that matches adb device ID?

Tags: android, uniqueidentifier, adb

Is there a way to get a unique device ID through code, and also get that same unique ID through adb?

The only unique ID that I know of through adb is the one shown when you type "adb devices", but I am unable to get this ID through code within an app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a great write up on this topic over at the [Android Developers Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html).  You should definitely check it out.

The identifier shown via "adb devices" is the device's serial number which is probably obtained from the USB information on the connection to the desktop.  If this is indeed the case, you may want to try:

[UsbDeviceConnection.getSerial()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbDeviceConnection.html#getSerial%28%29)

or

[Build.SERIAL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#SERIAL) but it's only available from API 9 (Gingerbread) forward.

Comment: Thanks. Build.SERIAL looks promising... Guess I can't really implement it until the majority or users are running 2.3 though :(